# How would you access an array from an array of pointers

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I was wondering how I would access or change parts of a string through an array of pointers. This is for a program that plays backgammon. That array of pointers points to over 24 different arrays. here is a sample of the code. I want to be able to know how many of each character there is in each 'r#' string. I need to be able to update each string as players move across the board.

```
char r1[] = {'R','R','|','|','|','\0'};
char r2[] = {'|','|','|','|','|','\0'};
char r3[] = {'|','|','|','|','|','\0'};
char *a[24] = {r1, r2, r3, r4, ... , r24};
```

minimal reproducible example

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    char r1[] = {"RR|||"};
    char r2[] = {"|||||"};
    char r3[] = {"WWWWW"};
    char r4[] = {"|||||"};
    char r5[] = {"WWW||"};
    const char * a[5] = { r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 };
    int to;      

   for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
        printf("enter number here: ");
        scanf("%d", &to);
        
        char *to_check = strchr(a[to-1], '|');
       
        if(to_check){
            printf("successful \n");
        }else{
            printf("unsuccessful \n");
    
        }
        
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: `int a[]` is not the right type for such an array for starters...

Comment: First of all you need an array of *pointers to `char`*. Secondly, you access the arrays just like any other arrays, like `a[X][Y]`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude would you treat it like a 2d array?

Comment: On another note, `char r1[] = { ... };` is exactly equal to `char r1[] = "RR|||";`

Comment: You could also do `const char *a[24] = { "RR|||", "|||||", "|||||", ... };`, or `char *a[24][6] = { "RR|||", "|||||", "|||||", ... };` if you want the array to be mutable. (Thanks, @SomeProgrammerDude)

Comment: `a` is an array, so you use it like any other array. Then as each element of `a` is a pointer you can use it like any other pointer, which includes using array indexing.

Comment: "I want to be able to know how many of each character there is in each 'r#' string." Are you aware of `strlen()`?

Comment: @FredLarson Considering that literal strings are non-modifiable, `const char *a[24]` would be better. Or if the data needs to be modified `char a[24][6]`.

Comment: @Yunnosch I am but would there be a problem using strlen() on a[i] to point to the specific array that I want

Comment: @bursikif: No, `strlen()` would work just fine, as long as each string is null-terminated.

Comment: You should describe the exact problem you are facing rather than trying to abstract it away. Adding a [mre] of what you are trying to do and telling us why it does not work for you would be a good idea too. Otherwise, your question seems like an XY problem, which is difficult to understand and to solve.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli I added an example of what i am trying to do. The problem I'm continuing to have is that the strstr and strchr read the value of the pointer and not the string

Comment: The example you added is completely different than your original code. You have one more level here!. `char r1[] = {"RR|||"};` is already an array of pointers itself, more precisely an array of one pointer to the string `"RR|||"`. If you write everything how you originally did in your initial question then all will be fine. You want `char r1[] = {'R','R','|','|','|','\0'};` or `const char r1[] = "RR|||"`. Beware that using the second option the string is not modifiable.

Comment: Moreover, you should get a warning from your compiler currently, because `const char * a[5] = { r1, r2, r3, r4, r5 };` is wrong since `r1..r5` are not `char *`.